# How can I send emails using Symfony, Swift Mailer, and Office 365?

Tags: symfony, smtp, office365, swiftmailer

I'm using Symfony 3.4 deployed in HostGator. I need send emails to my users in some cases. If I use Gmail, the emails are sent without problem, but when I use Office 365, I'm getting the following error:

> Connection could not be established with host

This is my email configuration:

```
parameters:
  mailer_transport: smtp
  mailer_host: ''
  mailer_user: example@mydomain.co
  mailer_password: 'mypassword'
  mailer_port: '587'
  mailer_smtp: 'smtp.office365.com'
```

Comment: To actually help you you should paste the `swiftmailer` configuration, not the `parameters`. To be sure that those values are used on the correct settings. For example @NabilAfraz's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would try pasting the 'smtp.office365.com' for the field: mailer_host

Answer (score 0):

Use host instead of mailer_smtp. I have this configuration for my swiftmailer. Hope it works for you.

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: 'smtp'
    host: '%mailer_host%' //  in your case : 'smtp.office365.com'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }
```